# Javascript simplified way for variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm beginner in Javascript and I speak English not very well, so sorry for this.
I've some code which is works but I would like to improve and simplified it.

-->what I currently have ( L.Icon is Leaflet icon ) :

```
let greenIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: './img/marker_green.png', shadowUrl: './img/marker-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41]
});
let redIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: './img/marker_red.png', shadowUrl: './img/marker-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41]
});
let orangeIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: './img/marker_orange.png', shadowUrl: './img/marker-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41]
});
```

-->what I would like to have if possible ( in this style ) :

```
let greenIcon, redIcon, orangeIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: './img/marker_**xxx**.png', shadowUrl: './img/marker-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41]
});
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is the `iconUrl`, so you can make a helper function that creates an icon with the passed `iconUrl` substring that differs:

```
const makeIcon = markerName => new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: `./img/marker_${markerName}.png`, shadowUrl: './img/marker-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41]
});
const greenIcon = makeIcon('green');
const redIcon = makeIcon('red');
const orangeIcon = makeIcon('orange');
```

But rather than having 3 separate standalone variable names for very similar values, I'd much prefer having a single object instead:

```
const icons = {
  green: makeIcon('green'),
  red: makeIcon('red'),
  orange: makeIcon('orange'),
};
```

Then you'd reference, eg, `icons.green` instead if `greenIcon`.